# JOptionPane won't appear

Tags: java, swing, class, joptionpane

i'm a beginner of java. and this is the very first time i encounter this problem. every time i run my program the `JOptionPane.showInputDialog` won't appear. here's my whole code can you see if there is something wrong:

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class StackTester {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Stack st=new Stack();

    String [] menu={"Set Capacity", "Push", "Pop", "Search", "Clear", "Exit"};
    String message="Capacity: "+st.getCapacity()+"\nElements: "+st.display()+
            "\nEmpty: "+st.isEmpty()+"\nFull: "+st.isFull()+
            "\n# of Elements: "+st.count()+"\nFirst: "+st.first()+"\nLast: "+st.last()+"\n";


    String choice="";
    int data=0;

    do{
        choice=(String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, message+"Input Choice:", "Menu", 1, null, menu, menu[0]);

        switch(choice){
        case "Set Capacity":
            st.setCapacity();
            st.getCapacity();
            break;
        case "Push":
            data=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter data: "));
            st.push(data);
            break;
        case "Pop":
            st.pop();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Popped!");
            break;
        case "Search":
            data=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter data to search: "));
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, st.search(data));
            break;
        case "Clear":
            st.clear();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Stack cleared");
            break;
        }
    }while(!choice.equals("Exit"));

}
```

}

i tried making another class and declared some `showMessageDialog` just to see if there is something wrong with the `JOptionPane` and not my code but it works. just here in this class nothing won't appear.

Comment: 1) Words typed in all lower case are hard to read, like trying to listen to someone who is mumbling.  Please use an upper case letter at the start of sentences, for the word I, and proper names like `ArrayList` or Oracle. 2) See [Detection/fix for the hanging close bracket of a code block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251795/155831) for a problem I could no longer be bothered fixing.

Answer (score 0):

Working fine for me. You can check it [here](http://prntscr.com/bzrcgk). Take a look at your build path, JDK and JRE versions. There might be a problem with routes.